# Does the current version of SDL allow for full window transparency?

Tags: sdl

Is it possible to use SDL to create a window with a transparent "hole" in it, i.e. with whatever application is beneath the SDL-driven application showing through? My understanding is that previous versions of SDL did not support this, so I'm hoping the latest version does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about SDL 1.2 then no , sdl 1.3 might have somthing like SDL_SetWindowShape 
but I would say you would like that